# Facebook app error: Try contacting your system administrator. ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

Tags: php, facebook, apache

I'm developing a Facebook app, and everything was worked fine until monday from when I can't open my app. The error says: This site can’t be reached

This site on the company, organization or school intranet has the same URL as an external website.

> Try contacting your system administrator.
>   ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

I've tried any of the solutions that I have found on the internet in the past two days, but I still got the same error.

The problem starts when I'm trying to start the app. I think the problem is my apache server, where I'm trying a couple of different solutions in the config files.

Any help?

Comment: What solutions you found on the internet have you tried? Please say that, once people don't know that. Another thing important to say is when does this error happens - site access/get or post/after login? Please, check [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Comment: The problem starts when i'm trying to start the app. I think the problem is my apache server, where i'm trying a couple of different solutions in the config files.

Comment: First, add in the question every detail (don't leave it just in comments). Also, if you think this is an Apache configuration and not a specific programming problem, you should post your question in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access your app at? This error may be caused by the specific name you're using.